# The effect of learning/expertise on cognitive control

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, reference-request, expertise, executive-function

[Rasmussen (1983)](http://reliability.com/industry/pdf/Skills-rules-knowledge-Rasmussen-seg.pdf) argued that with expertise, task are performed in different ways. He made a distinction between Rule- (least experience), Knowledge- and Skill-based behavior (most experience). The idea is that with training, less deliberate thought is necessary to perform a particular type of task.

Another factor that may play a role in task-performance is executive functioning, such as planning and cognitive control, i.e. the ability to focus on a task or switch tasks, either pro-actively or re-actively ([Braver, 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3289517/)). I've heard that with expertise, executive functions improve. However, I cannot find a reference to support this. **Is there any literature that may support this statement?**

#### References

[Braver, T. S. (2012). The variable nature of cognitive control: a dual mechanisms framework. Trends in cognitive sciences, 16(2), 106-113.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3289517/)

[Rasmussen, J. (1983). Skills, rules, and knowledge; signals, signs, and symbols, and other distinctions in human performance models. IEEE transactions on systems, man, and cybernetics, (3), 257-266.](http://reliability.com/industry/pdf/Skills-rules-knowledge-Rasmussen-seg.pdf)

Comment: Those two are the basics: Shiffrin, R. M., & Schneider, W. (1977). Controlled and automatic human information processing: II. Perceptual learning, automatic attending and a general theory. Psychological review, 84(2), 127.‏ Logan, G. D. (1985). Skill and automaticity: Relations, implications, and future directions. Canadian Journal of Psychology/Revue canadienne de psychologie, 39(2), 367.‏ Have fun :)

Comment: Possible explanation could be that when a task is learned it takes less attentional resources to execute it. Therefore there are more spare resources left for other cognitive tasks. I suggest you look at literature for mental workload, information processor theory, limited resources theory.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

I'll update this answer as I come across more papers, but here:

Alves, H., Voss, M. W., Boot, W. R., Deslandes, A., Cossich, V., Salles, J. I., & Kramer, A. F. (2013). Perceptual-Cognitive Expertise in Elite Volleyball Players. Frontiers in Psychology Front. Psychol., 4. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00036

> The goal of the current study was to investigate the relationship
>   between sport expertise and perceptual and cognitive skills, as
>   measured by the component skills approach. We hypothesized that
>   athletes would outperform non-athlete controls in a number of
>   perceptual and cognitive domains and that sport expertise would
>   minimize gender differences. A total of 154 individuals (87
>   professional volleyball players and 67 non-athlete controls)
>   participated in the study. Participants performed a cognitive battery,
>   which included tests of executive control, memory, and visuo-spatial
>   attention. **Athletes showed superior performance speed on three tasks
>   (two executive control tasks and one visuo-spatial attentional
>   processing task).** In a subset of tasks, gender effects were observed
>   mainly in the control group, supporting the notion that athletic
>   experience can reduce traditional gender effects. The expertise
>   effects obtained substantiate the view that laboratory tests of
>   cognition may indeed enlighten the sport-cognition relationship.

It isn't a precise confirmation of the statement; after all, it only finds a relationship between cognitive control and expertise *in a particular domain*. But it definitely supports the statement.

This article here:

Voss, M. W., Kramer, A. F., Basak, C., Prakash, R. S., & Roberts, B. (2009). Are expert athletes ‘expert’ in the cognitive laboratory? A meta-analytic review of cognition and sport expertise. Applied Cognitive Psychology, 24(6), 812-826. doi:10.1002/acp.1588

performs a whole meta-analysis on athlete expertise and cognitive performance and offers a lot of results confirming increased attentional performance, but specifically states (in the year 2009!):

> we found no studies that have examined classic executive function
>   measures such as task-switching, dual task performance, or inhibition

The article found [here](http://princeton.summon.serialssolutions.com/#!/search?bookMark=ePnHCXMwjV3LagMxDDQ5tQn9heJ7s7DR-nkLhJZ-QHs2m0Qme1kCcaGfX429LT300Lsk2AeyBs2M1-phBDd7LlXDdVaNPdM4VZXBW-HaYp4J62q3EkwUBMxY4-UfhRgodj1FuvveBshM39-rPb6b9HNdve9xVbEWsK2vy_PoPBV0B83zBS9MN2GAnubLdKz0p416f3l-O7x2yzUD3Qn4pos-5zx4BvjIgxv5TNyfKFuODu5pYcfSxK0TZADnmCAzQDDM3hyH0Zkd00Y9tbq_T650bW4R2O5SNBZHLQYoiQ7_jz4sRt0QqBdJfWypUKx83H6SLDa00aH29s8ASjdKffKwYpHqMpKk8lnoC_EkfQc) found that:

> Fencing experience and physical fitness facilitate a person's ability
>   to withhold action when necessary. The interactive nature of aerobic
>   fitness and sport expertise on action inhibition suggests that
>   cognitive control benefits most from the combination of physical and
>   mental training compared to when each is administered singly.

and I think I'm bored now! Hope this helps.